# AllegroServe Exception Handling

Tags: exception, lisp, common-lisp, allegro-cl

How can I avoid getting an error when passing as argument to the function [do-http-request](http://www.franz.com/support/documentation/current/doc/aserve/aserve.html#f-do-http-request) an invalid host.
Is there any way that I can catch the error like the Java's exception-handling mechanism ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, CL has a very nice condition system. One easy option would be wrapping the call to `do-http-request` in [`ignore-errors`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_ignore.htm), which returns `nil` (and the condition as a second value) if an error condition was signalled in the wrapped code. You could then check for `nil` afterwards.

If you want something more like exception handling in Java, just use [`handler-case`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_hand_1.htm) and add an appropriate error clause (I don't have AllegroServe installed, but I suppose you get a `socket-error` for providing a wrong URL – just change that part if I misread):

```
(handler-case
    (do-http-request …)
  (socket-error ()
    …))
```

If you need `finally`-like functionality, use [`unwind-protect`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_unwind.htm):

```
(unwind-protect
     (handler-case
         (do-http-request …)
       (socket-error (condition) ; bind the signalled condition
         …)                      ; code to run when a socket-error was signalled
       (:no-error (value)        ; bind the returned value
         …))                     ; code to run when no condition was signalled
  …)                             ; cleanup code (finally)
```

You can even get more fancy, and e.g. use [`handler-bind`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_handle.htm) to handle the condition stack upwards by invoking a restart somewhere down the stack, without unwinding it. For example, if `do-http-request` provided a restart to try again with another URL, you could handle your error condition by invoking that restart with a new URL to retry. I just mention this for the sake of completeness – it would be overkill for your use case, but being able to resume (possibly expensive) computations easily can be a rather convenient feature.